# При нажатии на кнопку приложение вылетает

Tags: java, android, android-on-click

При нажатии на кнопку приложение вылетает и появляется надпись `"Unfortunately, OnClick has stoped"`.

```
TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void Click(View view) {
        tv.setText("HELLO");
    }
```

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="HELLO"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="Click"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button" />
```

**вот что выдает logcat**:

> Process: com.example.sadie.onclick, PID: 5068
>                                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                    at com.example.sadie.onclick.MainActivity.Click(MainActivity.java:20)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>       06-19 01:34:01.044 5068-5068/com.example.sadie.onclick I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5068 SIG: 9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

видимо проблема в том, что ссылки на виджеты в разметке (результат работы метода (`findViewById()`) нужно получать после того, как разметка присоединена к активити (результат работы метода `setContentView()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}
```

Сейчас вы пытаетесь в методе клика обратиться к несуществующему виджету, так как результат поика виджета без подключенной разметки будет *null* и получаете экзепшен.

PS: имена методов в Java пишутся с маленькой буквы. Методы обратного вызова принято начинать с *on-* - `onClick()` - стоит соблюдать конвенцию, если вы хотите, чтобы другие разработчики не думали про вас всякие гадости :)

Comment: Спасибо большое ! Возился с этой ошибкой весь день .