# Прошу помочь выявить ошибку и решить её!

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-development

Здравствуйте, господа товарищи! =) 
Не могу понять, в чем ошибка приложения, т. к. я не пользуюсь виртуальным девайсом (процессор не поддерживается). Приходится пользоваться своим телефоном. Помогите выявить ошибку и решить этот недуг. Код следующий:

```
package com.arslee07.politeh.studio;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FloatingActionButton Notif = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.Notif);
//FloatingActionButton About = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.About);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Notif.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent NotifSwitch = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotifActivity.class);
            startActivity(NotifSwitch);


        }
    });
    Notif.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);


}
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536463/177345

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Перенесите

```
FloatingActionButton Notif = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.Notif);
```

в onCreate после

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло.

Comment: @ArsLee: удалите вот эту строку - `Notif.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);`

Comment: На этот раз приложение запустилось, но после нажатия на кнопку - краш.

Comment: @ArsLee: старайтесь прилагать к вопросу больше информации по части отображаемых Студией ошибок. Что за ошибки?

Comment: В том то и дело, что в студии ошибок нет. Я бы смог всё пофиксить, используя LogCat, но процессор не поддерживает виртуальные устройства. AMD как всегда у разбитого корыта.

Comment: @ArsLee в MainActivity это весь код? какой код в NotifActivity?

Comment: @ArsLee: [Run Android studio emulator on AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366453/run-android-studio-emulator-on-amd-processor)

Comment: @ArsLee:  Ну а как вам помочь? Что значит много? 2 тыс строк?